# Rails 4 Params Not Nesting When Form Submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using Rails 4 and nested forms. I want to associate the models so the model named Lead is the parent and associated with the model named QuoteMetal. I want someone to submit the forms and have rails write the information from the forms into tables of the database. Here are my models:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quote_metals
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_metals
end
class QuoteMetal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lead
end
```

Here is the form:

```
  <%= form_for @lead, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= f.label :notes %>
      <%= f.text_area :note, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= fields_for @quote_metal do |ff| %>       
            <%= ff.label :weight %><br>
            <%= ff.number_field :weight, class: "form-control" %>
                 ....
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

  <% end %>
```

And my controller:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lead = Lead.new
    @quote_metal = @lead.quote_metal.build
  end

  def create
    raise params.inspect
  end

  def show
  end

private

    def lead_params
        params.require(:lead).permit([:name, ..., 
            quote_metal: [:weight....])
    end

end
```

The output params I get is not nested. It looks like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"JYO/Yt/QBlytHsQaRe9+stzZvZn6xCI7ukeypMZZjpgnowktFcllLhhb2qXK/+45V5l+qJFg/5b4/yZdWLPvGg==",
 "lead"=>{"name"=>"Dick",...,"note"=>"asdf"},
 "quote_metal"=>{"weight"=>"65.20",....},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

How do I get the params to be nested and then write those nested params to a the tables that correspond to the models - one table for the lead and one table for the metal.

Comment: 1 - Did you add the the lead_id to the quote_metal model?  2 - also add the :lead_id to the strong params on both models. So for your lead model : quote_metal_attributes: [:lead_id, ...]

Comment: And also your form is wrong. You can't use f. on both the form_for and the nested fields_for

Comment: And you should also post your controller for both.

Comment: Your leads controller also looks wrong. You should also read through the documentation on associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I added the lead_id to the quote_metal table. Where else would I add it? Also, I am having problems with the .build - Do I need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    <%= fields_for @quote_metal do |ff| %>
```

To

```
    <%= f.fields_for @quote_metal do |ff| %>
```

Prefixing `fields_for` with the form builder for the parent will scope this properly for you.

Separately, you might also consider refactoring your `quote_metal` nested view into a partial.

Comment: Thank you. Certainly solved one issue I was having but still am not able to write the information to the table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you should post a new question for that part with your controller code create action.  This question shows the .inspect call which is a nice debugging approach that might help others.

Comment: Or, update your question with the real content of your `update` action, not just `raise params.inspect` cause it's not really helpin us ^^"